# Роутинг codeigniter

Tags: php, маршрутизация, codeigniter

Очень нужна помощь. Убрал index.php из адресной строки, перестал работать роутинг. 
Захожу на `site.ru/search` не работает, а когда на `site.ru/index.php/search` перенаправляет на функцию контроллера
роутинг  `$route['search'] = "library/search";`

.htaccess выглядит так:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|public)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpg|gif|png)$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: AllowOverride есть для vhost ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$config['index_page'] = ''; //здесь ничего не должно быть
```

исправьте в конфиге (`application/config/config.php`)